Implementing territory capture in a 2D strategy game in Godot 4
I'm developing a 2D game in Godot 4 and I want to implement a territory capture mechanic, similar to what you see in games like Age of History. The idea is for a player to gradually "paint over" an enemy territory with their own color as they conquer it. I'm wondering if I need to change my current map creation process to accommodate this feature. My current map creation method involves creating a background PNG image of the world map with superimposed textures and colors for each country. On top of this, I layer each country individually as transparent vector svg files within the engine, and create collisionpolygon2d so the player can select any country. Additionally, I'd like to avoid using a province-based system.

It sounds like you have what you need to be able to dynamically re-colour countries as they're captured. How have you tried implementing this so far, and where have you gotten stuck, or gotten results that differ from what you want?
